# Add new column of buttons to existing Jqgrid and access rowdata using the button

Tags: jqgrid

My jqgrid has data in each row ,for each row i should add a button in the grid,click on a button should access the rowdata and generate the graph for same...help me out how to add a new column with buttons in it and how to get rowdata

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some code? We help, but we don't do your work.